# Cashing Foreign checks

Tags: check

My brother is sending me a check from Germany. Can I cash that foreign check at any United State Bank?  I have tried to research all the possibilities.

Comment: Do note that deutsche bank for example does have branches here (not that that necessarily makes things faster or easier, I haven't researched that).

Answer (score 0):

Best to bring it into a branch where you have an account. They will charge you a commission on the currency exchange. You'll have to wait for the funds to clear.